# Memory assigned to c code is much less than it is supposed to use

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, multidimensional-array

I am new to this forum...

I am working on a DSMC C code which is supposed to utilise 500MB of RAM space, as i have calculated considering `sizeof(double)==8` and `sizeof(int)==4`.
yet when i run the code the task manager of my windows8.1 shows only 172 MB of ram being used by the code.exe file.. why could this be happening... ?
I am using 10-15 really long multidimensional arrays like .. `var_name[3][4050000]`.
this concerns me as the result I need is also not as expected..

All the variables are defined outside `main()` and are defined as static...

```
#define MNC 202500
#define MNM 4050000
#define MNSC 16020000
...

static double PP[3][MNM],PV[3][MNM],CG[6][MNC],CT[MNC],CSS[9],CS[7][MNC],FDPCELL[MNC],FDPCELL1[4][4];
static int IR[MNM],ISCG[2][MNSC],IPL[MNM],ISC[MNSC],IC[2][MNC],DPCELL[MNC],DPCELL1[4][4],n;
static double NCOLM,NROW,NSLC,BMEJ;
static double TIME,FTMP,VFX,VFY,VFZ,VMP,TMPJ,FVJ,SELT,X,Y,Z;
...

int main()
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

it would be really great if anyone of you suggest me what could be wrong with such an unpredictable error...

Comment: Lot of things could come into play there. Without seeing your code, it's difficult to comment.

Comment: How exactly did you measure the 172MB? It's likely that pages of physical memory are allocated on demand when they're first accessed, so the process might not allocate all 500MB unless it uses it all.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Plread read [ask].  Please show the code.

Comment: Do you initialize every single array element of each array?

Comment: actually the code is more than 1200 lines... but here are some imp fragments which helped me check the memory requirement of my code

Comment: @Mike... i got 172 MB value from the task manager of Win 8

Comment: @Damon... once globally defined... all the arrays have data written to them by the functions in the code depending on various test conditions..

Comment: That rules out the "pages are never created" theory. Then maybe whatever TaskManager displays is just rubbish. I'd try using a better tool (say Sysinternals thingie) if it really matters, or not bother at all as long as the code performs correctly.

Comment: @Hamzaa: And what exactly was the task manager measuring? I don't use Windows much, but I'm fairly sure it can give several different memory statistics, with different names, not just some vague notion of "ram being used".

Comment: @Hamzaa - please edit the code into the question.

Comment: Task Manager has multiple memory columns available.  I believe the default one shows the working set, i.e., the fraction of the allocated memory that Windows has chosen to assign to physical RAM.  The remainder of the memory might not have been initialized yet, or might have been swapped out because it hasn't been used recently.

Answer (score 1):

Various things can cause this behaviour:

- if some areas of those arrays are never accessed, the corresponding memory pages are never allocated in physical memory;
- your program won't probably use all the arrays at the same time, and at any time only a small slice of every array may be needed; in such situation, most of your arrays are swapped out of physical memory, dramatically reducing its usage.

Without seeing the code, these are the most probable causes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might be some issue in your code, and you really did allocate less than you think. Also, what Task Manager shows is what the OS is "handling" at the moment. The memory might have not yet been allocated by the OS for various reasons. Try using all that memory to see if the amount shown by Task Manager changes.

To be really sure about what amount of memory is allocated by the compiler, generate a MAP file and find the symbols (`var_name`) and see how much is exactly allocated.